Get multi data telemetry in rule engine thingsboard

I want to get 2 lastest telemetry in my device by using rule engine in thingsboard, but I can get it. The result returns the lastest telemetry.
How to get 2 lastest telemetry in thingsboard ?

And I had connected thingsboard to kafka, but when I post the data from DHT22 to the thingsboard, the telemetry change everytime despire of I don't change it in DHT22. And the data I had in the kafka is very cazy. Emxample:
First I change the data:
humidity: 20, temperature: 30
Second I change the data:
humidity: 23, temperature: 34


Because the data I post continuosly, the result must have been:
humidity: 20, temperature: 30
humidity: 20, temperature: 30
.....
humidity: 23, temperature: 34
humidity: 23, temperature: 34
.....
But the result I received is:
humidity: 20, temperature: 30
humidity: 23, temperature: 34
humidity: 20, temperature: 30
humidity: 23, temperature: 34
humidity: 23, temperature: 34
humidity: 20, temperature: 30
....

If your purpose is to debug, it is easier to create a new dashboard and insert a widget of Timeseries Table type, adjust the columns for the datapoints you want to see and the table will show a line for each telemetry sent.
